# How to center a particular section of your page so it lands perfectly with smooth-scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Not sure what I am doing wrong why my codes are not being centered: when i click on the button to do smooth-scoll this particular section of a bootstrap corosel template is not centered when it scrolled to this section.

Was reading another post on here 
[Center a section when using smooth scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281364/center-a-section-when-using-smooth-scroll)

about smooth scroll but the explanation doesn't help, is there an easier way? that is also from six years ago? 
Here is my codes and screen shots - the first pic is not centered when i click on the button. while the second pics centered perfectly. Why?

```
<!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
    <h2>Sports & Entertainment</h2>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
    <h2>Education</h2>
    <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
    <h2>Community Development</h2>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
  </section>
  </hr>
```

[image: Not being centered]
[image: center perfectly]

Comment: I saw your first pic and is perfectly center, what I missed? can you tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

**Explanation**

Add `d-flex flex-column text-center justify-content-center align-items-center` those classes in your `.row` class and it will center your specified code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex flex-column text-center justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
    <h2>Sports & Entertainment</h2>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex flex-column text-center justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
    <h2>Education</h2>
    <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex flex-column text-center justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
    <h2>Community Development</h2>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

## EDIT

After knowing the exact problem, you can solve it by adding

```
#projects {
    padding-top: 4rem;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nisharg the snippet shows that each item is centered, and stocked and on top of the other.. .

Comment: just did and taking back my comment..newbie mistake..my apologies..

Comment: I copied your code.. and it is still landing under the navbar.. no change..

Comment: the initial code has the home and this section as one.. i remove this section down a little further as it does not fit in to my page setup.. hence i think the reason stem from that, but not sure how to fix..

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/carousel/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212533/discussion-between-nisharg-shah-and-samantha).